# Exporting data from Microsoft Access table file subsets to plain text

Tags: ms-access, export

I have a problem in exporting data from Microsoft Access. I have an Access file made of several rows and columns, like this:

[image: Data table main data]

Every row contains a subset of data, tha could be observed by clicking on the "+" button:

[image: Data table subsets]

I would like to export all these data (main table & subsets), but there's a problem.
When I click on External Data -> Export -> Text file, Ms Access exports only the main table data (1st Figure), and completely omits the data of the subsets (2nd Figure).

**How could I export all these data (main table & subsets)?**

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Access does not know how you want the files exported when you use the standard "export" text function.

Here is a trivial piece of code that you can add to a Module, and run from a Command Button on a form, or directly from the Immediate Window:

```
Public Sub ExportTables(ByVal DestinationPath As String)

    Dim a As Long

    For a = 0 To CurrentDb.TableDefs.Count - 1
        If Not (CurrentDb.TableDefs(a).Name Like "MSys*") Then
            DoCmd.TransferText AcTextTransferType.acExportDelim _
                , _
                , CurrentDb.TableDefs(a).Name, DestinationPath & "\" & CurrentDb.TableDefs(a).Name & ".csv" _
                , True
        End If
    Next a

End Sub
```

Add a Module to your Access database, and paste in the code above.  Press "CTRL-G", enter `ExportTables "C:\temp"`, then press `Enter` - this will export all tables in the database into `C:\TEMP` in comma-separated-values format (.CSV) ready for import into Excel or other databases.